# Is concat in dask dataframe lazy operation?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-delayed, dask-dataframe

I'm reading a list of files using dask read_parquet and concatenate those data frames and writing to some file. during the concatenate, does dask read's all the data in to memory while concatenating or it is loading only schema's,  concatenate(I'm doing concatenation with  axis 0) ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

"Dask DataFrame is *lazy by default*" see [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html#persist-intelligently) so unless you fire `compute` it's just working with schemes.

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3))

ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=2)
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(df2, npartitions=2)

ddf = dd.concat([ddf1, ddf2])
print(ddf)
```

```sh
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                     0        1        2
npartitions=4                           
               float64  float64  float64
                   ...      ...      ...
                   ...      ...      ...
                   ...      ...      ...
                   ...      ...      ...
Dask Name: concat, 8 tasks
```